# Two-penny problem in Casella & Berger

Tags: probability, proof-explanation

There is the following exercise in Casella:

> Two pennies, one with $P(\text{head})=u$ and one with $P(\text{head})=w$, are to be tossed together independently. Define
> \begin{align*}
> p_0 & =P(0\ \text{heads occur}),\\
> p_1 & =P(1\ \text{head occurs}),\\
> p_2 & =P(2\ \text{heads occur}).
> \end{align*}
> Can $u$ and $w$ be chosen such that $p_0=p_1=p_2$? Prove your answer.

I know the solution, but I am not sure how Casella's logic works about sample spaces.

In this exercise, the sample space has to be: $$S = \{HH, HT, TH, TT\}$$ since there are 2 throws of different coins.

However, what does the author exactly mean by $P(H) = u$? If we just use the intuition, it is evident. However, our sample space is NOT one coin. It is the set of 4 outcomes. Thus, IMO when talking about  $P(H) = u$ the author is really talking about $P(\{HH, HT\})$.

So, when the independence comes into play, it is NOT just $P(H \cap T) = P(H)P(T)$, which is intuitive, but incorrect to say. In reality, it is $$P(\{HH, HT\} \cap \{HH, TH\}) = P(\{HH\}) = P(\{HH, HT\})P(\{HH, TH\})$$ Thus, as I understand we are supposed to assign the probabilities of $P(H)$ to $P(\{HH, HT\})$. However, Casella never mentions any kind of similar thought about this anywhere. Moreover, in the text, he casually jumps in between the sample spaces without assigning any probability. For example, in his "4 aces in 4 cards"-example, he jumps in between the sample space of combinations of 4 cards against sample spaces of combinations of three or less cards, but preserves the probability function.

For example, first talking about the probability of 4 aces from 52 cards, unordered, where the sample space is $52\choose 4$. But then, he talks about probability of 3 aces from 52 cards, which is clearly a restricted subspace since only 3 card draws, of size $52 \choose 3$. Then, the author contradicts himself when he says the event '4 aces from 4 cards' a subset of "3 aces from 3 cards", because the sample spaces are different:

[Conditional Probability Question, from Casella and Berger](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3818811/conditional-probability-question-from-casella-and-berger)

How do I properly think about this?

And if we move from a sample space of, say, 4 outcomes ($S = \{HH, HT, TH, TT\}$), into the reduced space of $\{H, T\}$, how can I be sure that the probability function is actually preserved? E.g. for the first coin toss: $P(H) = P(\{HH, HT\})$?

Comment: @P.J. no. In your example, you again treat the sample space $\{HH, HT, TH, TT\}$ as sample space $\{H, T\}$. How do you perform this conversion?

Comment: Okay. In probability there is often abuse of notation, which can prove to be tricky when learning. In this case, $ P(H) = P((HH) \cup (HT) \cup (TH))$, and that is because the coins are not necessarily identical, and hence the event $ TH$ is not the same (in an intuitive sense!) as the event $HT$. I do not fully understand what you are asking, could you perhaps elaborate in your question?

Comment: @P.J. i also feel like this is abuse of notation. however, Casella often jumps between different sample spaces: like you showed above -the problem is in the space $\{HH, HT, TH, TT\}$, but all the calculations are done in $$\{H, T\} by the author. Here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3818811/conditional-probability-question-from-casella-and-berger for example, Casella jumps from the space of 4 cards ($52\choose 4$) into space of 3 cards of size $52\choose 3$. I want to know, if it is abuse of notation, or it is legit to do: how I proceed to not make mistake in complex situations.

Comment: The 1st penny has sample space $\{H_1,T_1\}$, the second penny has sample space $\{H_2,T_2\}$, the whole experiment has sample space $\{H_1H_2,H_1T_2,T_1H_2,T_2H_2\}$. Does that clarify things?

Answer (score 1):

Consider throwing one coin. Then the sample space for this random experiment, as you know, is ${H,T}$, since there are only two possibilities - heads or tails. Now, when it comes to the problems you mentioned, we can be more explicit, and consider adding **phantom coins/cards/die** in the following manner:

Suppose the main random experiment you are considering is that of two coins being thrown. Then, consider two separate random experiments -

1. One real coin and one phantom coin being thrown (both are identical in all respects)
2. Two real coins being thrown

The sample space for  the second experiment is straightforward - $\{HH, HT,TH, TT \}$. But for the first random experiment, consisting of one real coin and one phantom coin, we write the sample space as - $\{\{HH,HT\},\{TH,TT\}\}$. In this way, the cardinality of the sample space is $2$, which makes sense because there is only one **real** coin, the other phantom coin is to help us make sense of everything. So when we say $P(H)$, (wrt the first random experiment) we mean $P(\{HH,HT\})$. In a way, it doesn't matter if the second coin is thrown or not, because we are not concerned with its outcome, hence we always cover all possibilities wrt the second, phantom coin.

In a similar vein, when we consider the experiment of drawing three cards from a deck, we can draw one more **phantom** card. Therefore, when we consider the event of drawing $3$ aces, our $4^{th}$ phantom card can be anything (apart from what we have drawn already, that is). Thus, the event $A$ - drawing 3 aces from 3 cards, has a whole lot of elements, when we consider the $4^{th}$ phantom card. The number of possibilities is exactly $52-3 = 49$. Thus the event that our phantom card is also an ace, is a subset of the event $A$.